# How can you use Credit Card test credentials to test out a Webform-CiviCRM form that uses a Contribution page?

Tags: webform-civicrm

Title pretty much says it all. I want to be able to run some tests of Contributions via a Webform.

I have test credentials for the Credit Card, so i can use 'test mode' on the contribution page directly, but can't see any way to set the webform to use the test option.

Maybe it is just a feature waiting to be asked for?

Comment: I always live test with fake credit cards (put the test URLs in the live payment processor config section). It's the only way I'm reassured things are working fine because what I want to test is the is_live pathways not the is_test pathways.

Answer (score 2):

There is a field on the Contribution tab within the CiviCRM tab of webform. The field is called "Payment Processor Mode" and gives you the following options
-User select-
Live transactions
Test Mode

[image]

Comment: wow. +1 for younger eyes than mine